# Mi concatenación de ciclo "FOR" no continua avanzando después del delimitador

Tags: c++, bucle-for

este codigo se trata de **concatenar los valores hasta el delimitador y continuar concatenando para rellenar la matriz**, pero la lectura del ***número se repite desde el 0 y no continua***... Un ejemplo de lo que me sucede es el siguiente:

```
1
16
166
1664
16643
166436
1664362
16643625
166436250
1664362500
16643625000
166436250000
1664362500000
1664362500000,


1
16
166
1664
16643
166436
1664362
16643625
166436250
1664362500
16643625000
166436250000
1664362500000
1664362500000,
...
```

*El código resultante es el siguiente:*

```
std::string mvalores [50] [12];//convetir string en tabla pasando las letras a char y luego designarlas a una casilla de la matriz concatenando la variable actual con el nuevo char hasta llegar al delimitador

std::string DATA = "1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0,1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0,"
//los parentesis los puse para que se entienda mejor la delimitacion de columnas. asi se aprecia mejor la idea: (1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0),(1664142300000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000078,792711162.0,1664142599999,615.63636645,6,524877171.0,409.40419338,0),(1664142600000,0.00000077,0.00000078,0.00000077,0.00000077,1083374165.0,1664142899999,834.63467174,7,43656469.0,34.05204582,0)";

std::string from4 = ","; //defini el delimitador
std::string::size_type pos4 = 0; // definí la posición inicial para encontrar el delimitador

/*El siguiente código hace lo siguiente, busca cada string de la 
variable DATA y lo va concatenando hasta encontrar el delimitador 
",", luego, una vez concatenado hasta el primer delimitador, se 
rellena la fila 1 de la columna 1... cuando finaliza el rellenado, 
el código busca cada string desde el primer delimitador hasta el 
segundo delimitador, luego concatena cada string desde el primer 
delimitador hasta el segundo delimitador y luego se rellena la 
columna 1 fila 2, y así sucesivamente hasta que llega al final de 
la fila y pasa a una nueva columna para rellenar... osea, los 
valores entre las "," se van rellenando en la matriz de fila en 
fila, pasa a una nueva columna y se siguen rellenando de fila en 
fila pero en la siguiente columna*/

for(int fil=0 ; fil <=49; fil++){ //añadí el número de filas
    for(int cols=0 ; cols <=11; cols++){ //columnas
        pos4 = DATA.find(from4, pos4); //encontrar la distancia del delimitador medido en caracteres.

        for (int i=0 ; i <= pos4 ; i++){ //posicion de los caracteres de DATA para que se vallan concatenando hasta llegar a la ","
            mvalores[fil][cols] = mvalores[fil][cols] + DATA[i]; //concatenación
            std::cout << mvalores[fil][cols] << std::endl; //muestra los valores desde el principio para ver los resultados completos (solo prueba).
        }
    }
}
```

Podria ser que el problema se encuentre en la variable "**i**" del último ciclo for, por lo que intenté resolver esto agregando una nueva variable int fuera de los ciclos para que no se me "**reseteara**" y esto fue lo que pasó:

```
1
16
166
1664
16643
166436
1664362
16643625
166436250
1664362500
16643625000
166436250000
1664362500000
1664362500000,/solo se mostró una vez.
```

es como si **pos4 = DATA.find(from4, pos4);** solo me encontrara el primer delimitador ","

Mientras tanto hare el sistema para eliminarla "," de la casilla final con la que se rellenara la matriz ("1664362500000,") para que no se agregue a la matriz

Comment: La pregunta no está bien redactada y no se entiende demasiado bien. ¿Qué es `DATA`? ¿Cual es su contenido? ¿Que salga la coma es un comportamiento esperado? ¿Cual es la salida que esperas? Por mucho que sea algo explicado en preguntas anteriores, si esperas que la gente se tenga que leer todas tus preguntas para poder responderte a la actual no te van a hacer mucho caso

Comment: la verdad está bien explicado pero quizá no se entendió mucho, es **un texto con delimitador ","**... quiero **almacenar cada conjunto de strings que existe entre las "," para añadir cada conjunto a una matriz**, mientras tanto añadiré el contenido de la variable **std::string DATA; **

Comment: Entiendo, si no se entiende la reescribire en este instante

Answer (score 0):

> es como si pos4 = DATA.find(from4, pos4); solo me encontrara el primer delimitador ","

Realmente es lo que te está pasando.

Supongamos la secuencia

```
DATA = "1111,2222,3333";
```

Como ves, hay un separador en la posición 4.

Ahora hacemos la llamada

```
pos4 = DATA.find(from4, pos4);
```

con lo que tendríamos que

```
pos4 = 4;
```

Extraes los valores y vuelves a hacer la llamada:

```
pos4 = DATA.find(from4, pos4);
//                      ~~~~
//                        4
```

Y lo que sucede es que `find` empieza a buscar en la posición 4. Dado que en esa posición encuentra un separador, deja de buscar y te devuelve su posición. Vuelves a obtener el valor 4 ... y así llamada tras llamada.

Tienes que hacer un par de cambios:

- Incrementar `pos4` en una unidad:

  ```
    pos4 = DATA.find(from4, pos4 + 1);
  ```
- Verificar que no has encontrado más separadores.

  Este paso es importante porque llegará un momento en el que `find` ya no encontrará más separadores en la línea. En ese momento devolverá `std::string::npos`. ¿Y cuánto vale `npos`? Pues de acuerdo con la [documentación](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/npos/)

  > This constant is defined with a value of -1, which because size_t is an unsigned integral type, it is the largest possible representable value for this type.

  Que viene a decir lo siguiente:

  > Esta constante está definida con el valor -1. Como size_t es de tipo unsigned int, éste será el valor más grande representable por este tipo

  Esto para tu algoritmo actual es un problema ya que acabarás accediendo a memoria que no pertenece al `string`. Tienes que protegerte ante esta situación:

  ```
  size_t new_pos4 = DATA.find(from4, pos4 + 1);
  if (new_pos4 != std::string::npos)
  {
      pos4 = new_pos4;
  }
  else
  {
      // No hay más delimitadores
      // quizás aquí debas buscar el paréntesis de cierre
      // y, si éste no se encuentra, terminar con el bucle
      new_pos4 = DATA.find(")", pos4);
      if (new_pos_4 != std::string::npos)
      {
          pos4 = new_pos4;
      }
      else
      {
          // No se ha encontrado el paréntesis ...
      }
  }
  ```

Ahora bien, con lo visto hasta ahora fíjate en un detalle importante, `i` debería ser de tipo `size_t`, no `int`. No es buena idea mezclar tipos con signo con tipos sin signo

```
 for (size_t i=0 ; i <= pos4 ; i++){
```

Sin este cambio, si se diese el caso de cadenas realmente grandes, `i` podría llegar a tener valores negativos y eso tendría efectos devastadores sobre tu programa

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, añadi el cambio a la variable "i", pero pos4 + 1 no me funciono, hice esto: **pos4 = DATA.find(from4,pos5); for (int posicionanterior; posicionanterior <= pos4 ; posicionanterior++){mvalores[fil][cols] = mvalores[fil][cols] + DATA[posicionanterior];} pos5 = pos4 + 1; std::replace(mvalores[fil][cols].begin(),mvalores[fil][cols].end(), ',', '\0'); ** si lo añades a tu editor de código se apreciara mejor el cambio pero hice esto: **pos4 = DATA.find(from4,pos5);** y luego después del último ciclo for, cerrando la llave agregue **pos5 = pos4+1;** y agregue un reemplazo de la ","

Comment: ah e hice que la variable i estuviera fuera del ciclo, para que no se reseteara la posición del carácter leído en la variable tipo String DATA